# How to create an Index of a bucket which is having password authentication in Couchbase server through cbq?

Tags: node.js, couchbase, sql++

How to create an Index of a bucket which is having password authentication in Couchbase server through cbq?

create primary index on `bucketName`,`password`;

Not Working?

Comment: Could you please correct the spelling of Couchbase in the title of the question?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say the name of you bucket is bucket1 and the password on the bucket is abc123.

This is how we create indexes/query that bucket using cbq when already in a cbq session. (As Gerald suggested, using \SET command)

```
cbq> \SET -creds bucket1:abc123;
cbq> create primary index on bucket1;
cbq> select * from bucket1 where ..... ;
....
```

If you are starting up cbq then you can also do the following. (As Gerald suggested above use the -c or --credentials option)

```
# ./cbq -c="bucket1:abc123" -e=http://<ur ip>:8091
cbq> create primary index on bucket1;
....
```

The bucket name is the bucket username. If you want to pass in or set the administrator credentials, then you use -u.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Couchbase 4.5, you can pass bucket credentials in the 4.5 cbq shell. See http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/tools/cbq-shell.html

You can use the -c or --credentials command line option, or you can run \SET -creds in the shell.

Finally, your index statement would simply be

```
CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON `bucketName`;
```

The cbq shell takes care of passing the credentials for you.

Comment: I am new to couch. Executed the following command \set `bucketname` bucketusername:password; . But throwing syntax error.                                    Can you please tell how to use \SET for a specific bucket?

Comment: Go ahead and fix the spelling in the title of the question, and then we will go from there.